# No puedo cerrar un JFrame

Tags: java, java-swing

Pues he intentado ya tantas cosas que no se como ni donde empezar.

Estoy haciendo un programa al cual es necesario logarse. Una vez que te logueas, se accede a un `JFrame` con tres paneles: uno a la izquierda con botones para acceder a cada aplicacion, otro arriba con una imagen y otro en el centro que es donde se colocan los paneles de las diferentes secciones que estan creadas desde sus propias clases.

Una de esas clases es el del usuario y desde pretendo hacer un logout y volver al `JFrame` del Login.

Y aqui es donde radica el problema, cuando quiero hacer el logout, el `JFrame` principal no se cierra, ni desaparece.

He probado con el metodo `dispose()`, configurando el `defaultCloseOperation`, con `actionListener` y cualquier posible solucion que haya podido encontrar tanto en espanyol como en ingles.

La nota curiosa de esto es que si coloco un boton para cerrar el `JFrame` principal, lo cierra, pero cuando lo hago a traves del metodo `doClick` ya sea en la misma clase o desde otra clase, no funciona.
[image: Screenshot del programa en funcionamiento]

Espero que me hayais entendido y podais darme alguna pista.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Francisco

PD: estoy con un ordenador con teclado ingles, por eso no puedo poner tildes ni la enye.

Comment: ya intentaste tener una variable con los otros formularios y sobreescribir dispose para que al cerrar uno active otro? Si usas spring puedes ver como corregi ese problema en un codigo que halle en internet y revivi https://github.com/javatlacati/Inventarios usando un patron visitador https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/visitor/

Comment: frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));

Comment: @Dramaturgo, gracias por tu respuesta. Ya lo utilice y no hubo resultado.

Comment: @RuslanLópez, gracias por tu respuesta. Finalmente he hecho un pequenyo cambio de disenyo y he dejado el JButton1 que se ve en el screenshot como el boton para el logout, pero mas bien como en forma de texto (quitando la forma y el background del boton y dejadolo con un label).
Igualmente me surge una duda: crees que con el javax.swing.JFrame se pueden crear clases padres-hijas?

Comment: @FranciscoJoséBejaranoEscaño si, de hecho en el codigo que ves se usa el patron singleton para evitar problemas de estado, como que se reinicie el frame al abrirlo por segunda vez.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente he decidido dejar el boton de logout fuera del CardLayout y ponerlo en panel fijo, como es el panel superior:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que la solucion sigue siendo elegante y funcional, aunque no era mi primera opcion. Utilizando esta manera, conseguia la opcion de cerrar la ventana tan solo que el dispose().